# How to generate all combinations of partitioning a string in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Given a string, how do you generate all partitions of it (shown as smaller strings separated by commas)? 
Also, what is the total number of partitions for a string of length n?

The following will give the result, but is not good on long strings.

```
String: CODE

C,O,D,E
C,O,DE
C,OD,E
C,ODE
CO,D,E
CO,DE
COD,E


String: PEACE

P,E,A,C,E
P,E,A,CE
P,E,AC,E
P,E,ACE
P,EA,C,E
P,EA,CE
P,EAC,E
PE,A,C,E
PE,A,CE
PE,AC,E
PE,ACE
PEA,C,E
PEA,CE

Sub getAllComb()

    oriStr = TextBox1.Text
    Dim tmp = ""
    Dim k = 0
    For i = 0 To oriStr.Length
        For j = 1 To 3
            'tmp = Mid(oriStr, i, j)
            Try
                tmp1(k) = oriStr.Substring(i, j)
                k = k + 1
                'tmp = oriStr.Substring(i, j)
                'Debug.Print(tmp)
            Catch ex As Exception
                'Debug.Print("Error>>>>" + ex.Message)
                Exit For
            End Try

        Next
    Next
    tmp = ""
    For i = 0 To k
        Debug.Print(i.ToString + "<i " + tmp1(i))
        tmp = tmp & tmp1(i) & vbCrLf
    Next
    'MessageBox.Show(tmp) 


    Dim tmpAll1 = ""

    tmpAll1 = addFunclen4(k)


    MessageBox.Show(tmpAll1)
    Debug.Print(tmpAll1)

    TextBox1.Text = oriStr & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & tmpAll1
End Sub



Function addFunclen4(k As Integer) As String
    Dim retVal = ""
    Dim tmp = ""
    Dim tmpAll = ""
    Dim tmpStr = ""
    Dim tmpAll1 = ""
    For i = 0 To k
        For i1 = 0 To k
            For i2 = 0 To k
                For i3 = 0 To k
                    For i4 = 0 To k

                        tmp = Form1.tmp1(i) + Form1.tmp1(i1) + Form1.tmp1(i2) + Form1.tmp1(i3) + Form1.tmp1(i4)
                        If Form1.tmp1(i) <> "" Then
                            If tmp = Form1.oriStr Then
                                tmpStr = Form1.tmp1(i) + "," + Form1.tmp1(i1) + "," + Form1.tmp1(i2) + "," + Form1.tmp1(i3) + "," + Form1.tmp1(i4)
                                Do While tmpStr.Contains(",,") = True
                                    tmpStr = Replace(tmpStr, ",,", ",")
                                Loop
                                If Mid(tmpStr, tmpStr.Length, 1) = "," Then
                                    tmpStr = Mid(tmpStr, 1, tmpStr.Length - 1)
                                End If

                                If tmpAll1.Contains(tmpStr) = False Then
                                    tmpAll1 = tmpAll1 + tmpStr + vbCrLf
                                End If
                            End If

                        End If
                    Next
                Next
            Next
        Next

    Next
    retVal = tmpAll1

    Return retVal
End Function
```

Comment: you've tagged Java and VB.net, two completely different languages. Which are you interested in?

Comment: What's the java tag doing here if it's about vb.net?

Comment: Please show us some more examples :)

Comment: @Arlind I have tried for small length of string but, long length is quite time consuming.

Comment: @brso05 see the upper code . i have added.

Comment: this looks like an n^6 logarithm, try making it simpler

Comment: @Arlind how to make simplier? Could you elaborate ?

Comment: @5uperdan interested in vb.net

Comment: try using a simpler algorithm by removing the loops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reckon [2^(n-1) - 1] in total:
(n-1) positions to put a comma, 2 "states" (comma or not comma), -1 for the trivial case with no commas.

A simpler algorithm would be to iterate through the number of cases and use the binary representation to determine whether to put a comma in each position.

For example (simple form with TextBox, Button and ListBox):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    Dim s As String = TextBox1.Text

    If s.Length < 2 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Enter a longer string")
        Return
    End If

    For i = 1 To Math.Pow(2, s.Length - 1) - 1
        Dim result As String = s(0)
        For j = 1 To s.Length - 1
            result = result & CommaOrNot(i, j) & s(j)
        Next
        ListBox1.Items.Add(result)
    Next
End Sub

Private Function CommaOrNot(i As Integer, j As Integer) As String
    If (i And Math.Pow(2, j - 1)) = Math.Pow(2, j - 1) Then
        Return ","
    Else
        Return ""
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I really liked Fruitbat's approach. Here's an alternate version using a slightly different mechanism for the representation of the binary number and how to determine if the comma should be included or not:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private combinations As List(Of String)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim s As String = TextBox1.Text
        If s.Length < 2 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Enter a longer string")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Button1.Enabled = False
        ListBox1.DataSource = Nothing
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Generating combinations...")
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(s)
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        Dim s As String = e.Argument
        Dim combinations As New List(Of String)

        Dim binary() As Char
        Dim values() As Char = s.ToCharArray
        Dim max As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(New String("1", s.Length - 1), 2)
        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        For i As Integer = 0 To max
            sb.Clear()
            binary = Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(values.Length, "0").ToCharArray
            For j As Integer = 0 To values.Length - 1
                sb.Append(If(binary(j) = "0", "", ","))
                sb.Append(values(j))
            Next
            combinations.Add(sb.ToString)
        Next

        e.Result = combinations
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
        combinations = e.Result
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Generating combinations...Done!")
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Adding Results...one moment please!")
        Application.DoEvents()

        ListBox1.DataSource = Nothing
        ListBox1.DataSource = combinations
        Button1.Enabled = True
        MessageBox.Show("Done!")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: This works so fine and fast. used `sb.Remove(0, sb.Length)` in place of `sb.Clear()` . Thank you for the keeping in interest and reopening the question of course.